# How to turn Off iPhone application when enters in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, background-service

I have made an iPhone application.
When my application enters in background.
I want to turn off fully my iPhone application,and when i again start my iPhone application it should starts from the starting page,it should not start from where i left.
I have used exit(0),but i think it is not recommended by Apple.
Please provide some suitable solution soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by modifying your `info.plist` file.

add this Key **"Application does not run in background"** and set its value to **"YES"**

This should get you going!

Let me know if it solves:)